# Scroll inner div without scrolling outer parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, js-scrollintoview

How can I set some element in the inner div to scroll into view without scrolling the parent element? In the following example (I added some delay so the effect is more easily seen) you can see how the parent div scrolls even when it isn't needed for the target element to be scrolled into view by using just the inner div scroll.

```js
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("target").scrollIntoView({
  behavior: "smooth",
  block: "nearest",
}), 1000)
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.outer {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 10em;
  overflow: auto;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 5em;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div>Something</div>
    <div>Something</div>
    <div>Something</div>
    <div>Something</div>
    <div>Something</div>
    <div>Something</div>
    <div>Something</div>
    <div class="inner">
      <div>Something else</div>
      <div>Something else</div>
      <div>Something else</div>
      <div>Something else</div>
      <div>Something else</div>
      <div>Something else</div>
      <div id="target">Scroll me</div>
      <div>Something else</div>
      <div>Something else</div>
      <div>Something else</div>
      <div>Something else</div>
      <div>Something else</div>
      <div>Something else</div>

    </div>
    <div>Something</div>
    <div>Something</div>
    <div>Something</div>
    <div>Something</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is a simplified example to show the problem I want to solve by using pure js/css (my app uses react without any styling library added)

Comment: I don't think you can use `scrollIntoView` then; you will probably have to replace it with getting/calculating the offsetTop of `#target` within `.inner`, and then assigning that value as the [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) for `.inner`. And you can't specify that you want smooth scroll behavior when doing that, so you'll have to see if applying it via the `scroll-behavior` CSS property works in that situation.

Comment: I do notice, after [testing](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/RwEMpVb), that in Chrome and Firefox, on the desktop, both the parent and inner divs scroll. This makes perfect sense. They scroll just enough to make the target visible. So for the inner div that would be until the target is visible at the bottom, and the same is then true for the parent div. Sure you could make something that would only scroll the inner div, but they you also need to think of cases where the inner div is completely off-screen. Why go through all that effort when you already have a solution that works pretty well?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware As an analogous example to my use case you can think of a task list where each task in the list (outer div) is editable. The edition interface replaces de task and loads a small calendar like element (inner div) that shows the tasks of that day, and there I want to scroll to the current hour (potentially out of the screen). Doing a scroll for both lists potentially makes the UX a bit weird if you move around the fields with which the user is interacting in the moment.

Comment: Ah, OK, yes, so setting the `.scrollTop()` for the inner div, like CBroe suggested, should work for that. `ScrollIIntoView()` means that you want to make the element directly visible, which isn't your intention.